# I just added var React = require('react-native'); and my whole build failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just added

```
var React = require('react-native');
```

to my index.ios.js file but when I reload my React Native application, this
comes up:

[It says React is read-only?!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iODOm.png)

So I tried to change the permissions on the react-native module by doing

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ExampleProject
sudo chmod -R 777 ExampleProject/node_modules/react-native
```

but it still doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

---

This is the full source code of my index.ios.js file:

```
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
 'use strict';

 var React = require('react-native');

 import React, {
   AppRegistry,
   Component,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View
 } from 'react-native';

 class Logbook extends Component {
   render() {
   return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome to React Native!
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      To get started, edit index.ios.js
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
      Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
    </Text>
  </View>
  );
  }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
 },
 welcome: {
 fontSize: 20,
 textAlign: 'center',
 margin: 10,
 },
 instructions: {
 textAlign: 'center',
 color: '#333333',
 marginBottom: 5,
 },
 });

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Logbook', () => Logbook);
```

Comment: Can you include all the code your `index.ios.js` file?

Answer (score 4):

You actually import react-native two times. The second time around it complains. Just get rid of

```
var React = require('react-native');
```

This does the same thing but with the ES6 module syntax

```
import React from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Thank you! But why do they implement it two times in the official docs? And why does it say that 'React' is read-only? @dvine

Comment: I think you just found a bug in the docs :) Maybe you should open an issue or file a PR. I can do it if you want to.

I'm not 100% sure about the error, but my best guess is, that modules generate global constants somewhere. Usually when you import the same module twice it just takes the already imported module from the cache. But since you used two different module loaders to load the same module this somehow didn't work.